# Laravel Homestead Development: AJAX POST request gets redirected for unknown reason

Tags: ajax, laravel, redirect, post, homestead

I'm on Laravel 5.3 and I was working on a form I POST submit to the server. What I want to point out right at the beginning is that I have been working on this form for days, with no issues what so ever. Yesterday I was working in the store method of my controller, when all of a sudden the form won't submit at all anymore.

The opening form:

`{!! Form::model($addon = new \App\Addon, ['name' => 'FinalForm', 'route' => 'addons.store', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}`

My route:

```
Route::resource('addons', 'AddonController');
```

php artisan route:list:

> Method: POST
>
> URI: addons
>
> Name: addons.store
>
> Action: App\Http\Controllers\AddonController@store

Middleware: web,auth

So what happens now is, the form gets posted, but then, for some reason, get's redirected. This is what chrome says:

[POST request to /addons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPjxo.png)

[And after that, for some reason, GET request to /addons/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZeXk.png)

As you can see I'm getting a 403 Forbidden response. Why is the request being redicted to /addons/ ??

As I said before, I changed NOTHING, I was working with the inner logic of the store method on the controller when this popped up. I even restarted the homestead box (and my whole machine), I don't know what is causing it.

EDIT (controller):

```
/**
 * Store the addon.
 *
 * @return Response
 **/
 public function store(CreateAddonRequest $request, ImageHandler $imageHandler)
{   
    $input = $request->only('title', 'body', 'author', 'slogan', 'version', 'revision', 'published_at', '_img_data');
    $session = $request->session()->all();

    $slug = SlugService::createSlug(Addon::class, 'title', $input['title'], ['unique' => true]);
    $imageHandler->move($slug, $input['body'], 'description');
    $body = $imageHandler->body;

    $addon = Auth::user()->addons()->create([
        'body'          => $body,
        'title'         => $input['title'],
        'slogan'        => $input['slogan'],
        'author'        => $input['author'],
        'locales'       => $session['locales'],
        'published_at'  => $input['published_at']
        ]);
    $addon->categories()->attach($request->input('categories'));

    Storage::makeDirectory('addons/' . $slug . '/files/');
    $extension = Dir::extension('temp/' . $session['file_name']);

    if ($input['revision'] != "") {
        $file = $addon->slug . '-v' . $input['version'] . '-r' . $input['revision'] . '.' . $extension;
    } else {
        $file = $addon->slug . '-v' . $input['version'] . '.' . $extension;
    }

    Storage::disk('local')->move('temp/' . $session['file_name'], 'public/addons/' . $addon->slug . '/files/' . $file);

    // With 5.4 we don't need that check anymore
    if ($input['revision'] == "") {
        $input['revision'] = null;
    }

    $addon->files()->create([
        'file_name'     => $file,
        'hash'          => $session['hash'],
        'version'       => $input['version'],
        'revision'      => $input['revision'],
        'game_version'  => $session['interface'],
        'virustotal'    => $session['virustotal']
    ]);

    dd('done');

    // if ($request->hasFile('images'))
    // {
    //  Storage::makeDirectory('addons/' . $slug . '/images/');

    //  foreach ($request->file('images') as $image)
    //  {
    //      $imageName = uniqid() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    //      //$image->storeAs('addons/' . $slug . '/images/', $imageName);
    //      $addon->images()->create(array('image_name' => $imageName));
    //  }

    // }

    // flash('The addon has been uploaded.');

    // return redirect('addons');

    dd('done');

    return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Images checked',
        ]);
}
```

Comment: put your contorller codes here

Comment: @Ordidaad Sorry, look now.

Comment: By the way it was happening when I was working on the commented out section at the bottom. But still after commenting it out it doesn't work.

Comment: It's possible that your browser cached the 301 response and is now always redirecting without actually hitting the route.

Comment: did your create method work ? you call redirect helper here: return redirect('addons');

Comment: It's not the browser cache. I killed it a couple of times already.
@Ordidaad I'm sorry, what do you mean? the post request hits the controller method, and all I do for now is process the data and then dd('done');

Comment: ok, you say the browser redirect for no reason, right ? so what is that redirect helper call in the bottom of your codes ?